# How to return to the UK as a non-visa national after previously experiencing problems at the border?

Tags: visas, uk, denial-of-entry

I used to hold a Tier 4 student visa and had it terminated recently. Before my visa was terminated due to being withdrawn from my studies, I attempted to appeal the decision and was advised to return home as the appeal would have taken months. It did, and it failed. I had to return to pack and ship all my belongings. Flying back, I was detained for 11 hours, and after the interview only given temporary entry as a person liable to be detained. They took my passport, and cut my BRP which I had planned on keeping for sentimental reasons.

The major problem seemed to be the fact that I decided to stay for 43 days on my latest visit. I am a non-visa national so I assumed I would be allowed temporary entry for up to 3 months. But the IO told me I only have 14 days to pack everything and leave.

Two weeks was not really enough time. I had planned on applying for a visitor's visa and re-entering at a later date. However, recent events have required that I return as soon as possible and I won't have time to apply for an entry clearance.

How can I prove to the IO that I am a genuine visitor and receive a leave to enter the UK?

Comment: Didn't you post a question about this earlier? Reposting the same question won't get you an answer any quicker.

Comment: Yes I did, I thought I had to reword it since it was instantly marked as a duplicate due to a single sentence being identical with some other question.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here; perhaps you can clarify. Of course there is a significant risk that you'll be denied if you return. Nobody here can quantify that risk for you, but seeing as you just went through everything described above, it's self-evidently not low. Applying for entry clearance (a visa) will allow you to present all your documents and make your case, and if that is refused, at least it won't involve being detained in an airport for hours and sent back on another flight.

Comment: The only way to be confident that you would be admitted is to apply for entry clearance before you travel - other than that advice, we cant really answer your question as we are not entry clearance officers, we don't have all the details to hand, we don't have the official comments on your record etc etc etc.  Any attempt to answer would be essentially guess work.

Comment: "I had to reword it since it was instantly marked as a duplicate due to a single sentence being identical with some other question." No, it was closed because the people who listed as voting to close thought that your question was close enough to some other question that we didn't need to answer it again. Rephrasing the question doesn't change that. The closure message makes it quite clear that the process was entirely people-driven, and people simply do not do sentence-by-sentence comparisons.

Comment: @Moo The problem is I would not have the time to apply for entry clearance, as I am on a very very tight time frame. This is simply far too last minute.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to this question has been posted by Gayot Fow, a former immigration lawyer, [on his blog](https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/2017/11/23/uk-temporary-admission-to-a-person-liable-to-be-detained-returning-to-the-uk-without-a-visa/):

> Essentially the OP was a student who (apparently) dropped out and got
>   a curtailment. They went home to appeal and returned to the UK again
>   to collect their belongings.  They were detained at port and given a
>   14 day temporary admission.
>
> The OP is a non-visa national so can arrive in the UK without a visa,
>   but worries about the possibility of being detained again and possibly
>   removed.  The final sentence of the post is a question: “But would the
>   risk of being refused entry again be too high?”
>
> There’s too many unexplained pieces in the narrative to make an
>   educated guess, and the question is framed as an opinion poll in the
>   first instance.  If 10 random people say the risk is too high and 5
>   random people say the risk is not too high, what does it mean? Nada.
>
> So why waste time on this question at all?  Because there’s a fixed,
>   immutable piece of standard advice for anyone who has been detained or
>   given a temporary admission. And that piece of advice is: “*get an
>   entry clearance*“.  You can never be wrong on that aspect of the UK
>   Border Force.  Even if the person shows up without an entry clearance
>   and manages to get in, they are still better off having obtained a
>   visa beforehand.
>
> The other advantage to having an entry clearance is in future landing
>   interviews. Immigration Officers will always dwell on a temporary
>   admission when they see it. It means things will always be awkward,
>   even after a few years.  But what the person can say is “*Yes, that
>   event happened, and so I went home and successfully applied for an
>   entry clearance thus demonstrating a viable change in circumstances*”
>   (or words to that effect).  Off the hook. Enjoy your visit. Done and
>   dusted.
>
> So the question is not really an opinion poll at all. It’s
>   deterministic with a single answer: “*Pay the £89 and get an entry
>   clearance before chancing wasted airfares and the distress of removal
>   from port*“.

[CC BY-SA 3.0](https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/about/). Unchanged.

Comment: If you're curious why Gayot didn't post this from his own profile, [see this meta post](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4552/9009).