# Can you visit the UK after being refused entry to Ireland?

Tags: visas, ireland, denial-of-entry, common-travel-area

My friend went to Dublin through an agency but was denied entry as even though he had a return flight, digs set up and spending money; they did not believe he would go home.

He was sent back to the UK (where he had connected his flight to Dublin) where he was allowed entry for 48 hours, then left to go back to Brazil on his return flight without any problems.

My question is this, if he was to return to the UK? He now has a new clean passport as he lost his in return to Brazil.

Can he come back to the UK as a tourist? He genuinely has no intention of staying as he has family and work in Brazil.

Would the immigration computer systems have his refusal to Dublin logged? He had just a stamp and no fingerprints or photographs were taken in Dublin, just a refused entry stamp which has not shown on his replacement passport. Would this be logged anywhere as he is very scared to spend money on a flight if this will cause him problems.

Comment: It was in his hand luggage which was with him until he left the airport and his hand luggage was either stolen or more likely he lost it at the airport ! Not sure why that’s important, the body of the question is still the same!!!

Comment: I’ve edited the statement, I hope this helps clarify but the answer is what’s important if anyone could possibly help I’d be very grateful.

Comment: Although the background to this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105689/how-to-return-to-the-uk-as-a-non-visa-national-after-previously-experiencing-pro is different, the answer given is relevant: if in doubt about gaining visa-free entry, apply for entry clearance.

Comment: Did the UK hold his passport at the airport when he came in for 48 hours?

Comment: Hi Michael ,no they didn’t they just allowed him in for 48 hours, thank you traveller, I will check the link.

Comment: He can try, he is not guaranteed entry however the fact they allowed him 48 hours in UK after being denied entry to Ireland is to his advantage i.e. they have some trust for him. Changing passport means nothing, UK DEFINITELY have that information because they found out when he was returned to the UK airport before they gave him 48 hours. Above all he should never lie about what happened when applying for a visa or at the airport immigration.

Comment: Thank you Zealot, he will only tell the 100% truth. Thanks so much for your advice.i will advise him to apply for clearance before he leaves Brazil as he will at least not have that stress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a general point, changing passports won't make a difference. The refusal was against a person, not a passport, and it will have been logged.